# @JsonPropert to throw exception with all missed required fields

Tags: json, spring-boot, exception

The idea is to return all missing fields in `ArrayList` inside `ErrorResponseDto`. Currently, it fails on the first missing field occurrence and throws one single exception. For example: `"JSON parse error: Missing required creator property 'var1' (index 4)"`. How to make exception include all missing fields?

Exception hierarchy:
`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException`
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException`

Controller:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ServiceController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/action")
    public ResponseEntity verify(@RequestBody @Valid RequestDto RequestDto) {
}
}
```

DTO:

```
@Builder
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RequestDto {
    @JsonProperty(value = "var1", required = true)
    private String var1;

    @JsonProperty(value = "var2", required = true)
    private String var2;
}
```

GenericExceptionHandler:

```
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
@Component
public class GenericExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDto> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
List<ErrorResponseDto.ErrorResponse> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        errors.add(ErrorResponseDto.ErrorResponse.builder()
                .type(responseStatusCode.toString())
                .details(ex.getMessage())
                .build());

        ErrorResponseDto errorDetails = ErrorResponseDto.builder()
                .errors(errors)
                .build();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, responseStatusCode);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a custom implementation of `ConstraintValidator` will do a trick. [Examples](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/javaxval/src/main/java/org/baeldung/javaxval/methodvalidation/constraints/ValidReservationValidator.java)